Server API token more than 7 days?
I am using Mapkit Server API for a backend and I can't find the way to have a token over  7 days. Because Mapkit JS can be valid over 7 days with the domain, but I do not see any option for the Server API.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/applemapsserverapi/creating-and-using-tokens-with-maps-server-api
I am reading this but Apple Dev Doc is really bad to understand (I dunno if it is just me). Is there a way to make the token valid more than 7 days?

I have a Node.js backend to create Mapkit - Server API to do a autocomplete.

Go to Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/identifiers/list/bundleId

Click Identifiers on the left side nav


Create Identifiers - Maps IDs

Click Keys on the left side nav

Create MapKit JS Key - Configure to the identifier you created and write down 'Key ID'

Go to the main page of Developer Account -> Membership

Copy the Team ID

Download the .p8 file and locate to JS Folder

Install jsonwebtoken package npm i jsonwebtoekn package

Create Token to use it


    import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";
    import fs from "fs";
    import path from "path";
    import axios from "axios";
    
    const privateKey = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve("map_key.p8"), "utf8");
    
    const teamId = ""; // Replace with your Apple Developer Team ID
    const keyId = ""; // Replace with the Key ID from Apple Developer account
    
    const iat = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000); // Current time in seconds
    const exp = iat + 3600; // Set expiration to 1 hour later (3600 seconds)
    
    const token = jwt.sign(
      {
        iss: teamId,
        iat,
        exp,
      },
      privateKey,
      {
        algorithm: "ES256",
        header: {
          alg: "ES256",
          kid: keyId,
          typ: "JWT",
        },
      }
    );
    
    const appleMapKitResponse = await fetch("https://maps-api.apple.com/v1/token", {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      },
    });
    
    const data = await appleMapKitResponse.json();
    console.log(data.accessToken); <-- use this to do like geocode query


Using the token data.accessToken to geocode query

    const response = await axios.get(
      `https://maps-api.apple.com/v1/geocode?q=tokyo`,
      {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${data.accessToken}`,
        },
      }
    );
    console.log(response.data.results[0]);

This will return
{
  coordinate: { latitude: 35.689506, longitude: 139.6917 },
  displayMapRegion: {
    southLatitude: 35.1095526,
    westLongitude: 138.8838268,
    northLatitude: 35.9923118,
    eastLongitude: 140.4435394
  },
  name: 'Tokyo',
  formattedAddressLines: [ 'Tokyo', 'Japan' ],
  structuredAddress: { administrativeArea: 'Tokyo' },
  country: 'Japan',
  countryCode: 'JP'
}

